# How to get the last and first special chars of a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, split

I got a few string in an list:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("_+hello[]_");
mylist.Add("_+how||");
mylist.Add("_+are,,");
mylist.Add("||you=_");
mylist.Add("_+doing\"_");
```

I want to get the last and first special chars (+,_[]=") all in in array.

```
string[,] array = new string[5,2]
```

my array should look something like this on the end:

```
_+ AND [] _
_+ AND ||
_+ AND ,,
|| AND =_
_+ AND "_
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you come up with so far?

Comment: This makes no sense, you want the first character but want `_+` returned

Comment: Try `Regex.Split(str, @"[^\W_]+")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please post this as answer, it's brilliant

Comment: Posted two variants of the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to split with alphanumeric chars. Since `\w` matches alphanumeric or underscore chars, you can [**subtract**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) the `_` form it and use it with `Regex.Split`:

```
Regex.Split(str, @"[\w-[_]]+")
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cw-%5B_%5D%5D%2B&i=_%2Bhello%5B%5D_%0D%0A_%2Bhow%7C%7C%0D%0A_%2Bare%2C%2C%0D%0A%7C%7Cyou%3D_%0D%0A_%2Bdoing%22_)

Or

```
Regex.Split(str, @"[^\W_]+")
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%2B&i=_%2Bhello%5B%5D_%0D%0A_%2Bhow%7C%7C%0D%0A_%2Bare%2C%2C%0D%0A%7C%7Cyou%3D_%0D%0A_%2Bdoing%22_)

The `[^\W_]` matches any char that is not a non-word char (that is, it matches any `\w`) and not a `_` (so, any `\w` except `_` that otherwise would get matched).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Just don't try `"+hello there+"`

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: OP input contains no whitespace. Requirements for this scenario would be necessary. To avoid getting whitespace chunks, the pattern can be `[\w\s-[_]]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree it's undefined, but I bet he doesn't want _only_ these exact input values, otherwise he could just hardcode the result. OP has already accepted your answer, it's just something he might want to be aware of.

Answer (score -2):

```
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    mylist.Add("_+hello[]_");
    mylist.Add("_+how||");
    mylist.Add("_+are,,");
    mylist.Add("||you=_");
    mylist.Add("_+doing\"_");
    foreach (var item in mylist)
    {
        var LastItem=item.ToArray().Last();
        var FirstItem = item.ToArray().First();
    }
```